# Need help on Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
public class Zuora_Account implements NGTrigg.Executor {
   private List<Subscription__c> newSubscriptionList;
     private static Boolean HAS_BEEN_EXECUTED = false;
     public static final String CLASSNAME = 'Zuora_Account';

     public Zuora_Account(List<Subscription__c> newSubscriptionList){  
        system.debug('Enter Zuora_AccountUpdate constructor>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');     
        this.newSubscriptionList = newSubscriptionList;
     }

     public void execute() {
        Set<Id> acctIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<Account> acctToBeUpdated = new List<Account>();    
        try{
            if(HAS_BEEN_EXECUTED){
                return;
            }
            for (Subscription__c subscription : newSubscriptionList) {
                acctIds.add(subscription.Zoura_Account__c);
            }
            if( acctIds.size() > 0) {
                for(Account acctObj : [select DO_NOT_MERGE__c from account where id in : acctIds]) {

                    if( !acctObj.DO_NOT_MERGE__c || acctObj.DO_NOT_MERGE__c == false) {
                        acctObj.DO_NOT_MERGE__c = true;
                        acctToBeUpdated.add(acctObj);
                    }
                }
                if (!acctToBeUpdated.isEmpty()) {
                    system.debug('update account do not merge flag: ' + acctToBeUpdated);
                    update acctToBeUpdated; 
                }                   
            }                  
            HAS_BEEN_EXECUTED = True;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            String errMsg = ex.getMessage()+' at line '+ex.getLineNumber().format()+' in '+CLASSNAME;
            system.debug('Error:'+errMsg); 
            Log__c erroLog = new Log__c ();
            erroLog.Type__c = ex.getTypeName();
            erroLog.Log__c = ex.getMessage();
            erroLog.Business_Unit__c = CLASSNAME;
            insert erroLog;    
        }
     }
}
```

and test class

```
{@isTest
public class Test_ZouraAcc {

    public static testmethod void test_z_Acc(){

        List<Account> testAccounts = new list<account>();
        account acc1=new account();
        acc1.name='test1';
        acc1.DO_NOT_MERGE__c =false;
        testAccounts.add(acc1);
        account acc2=new account();
        acc2.name='test1';
        testAccounts.add(acc2);
        insert testAccounts;


        List<Subscription__c> zsubList =new list<Subscription__c>();
        Subscription__c sc1=new Subscription__c();
        sc1.name = 'TestSub1' ;
        sc1.Zoura_Account__c=testAccounts[0].id;
        zsubList.add(sc1);

        Subscription__c sc2=new Subscription__c();
        sc2.name = 'TestSub2' ;
        sc2.Zoura_Account__c=testAccounts[1].id;
        zsubList.add(sc2);
        insert zsubList;
        Zuora_Account za = new Zuora_Account(zsubList);
        za.execute();

    }
}
}
```

I am not able to cover Catch block 
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the above code I think 1 way of covering the catch block exception is to throw custom exception only to cover the catch block.

1. Create a new class that implements Exception which will be used to throw the custom exception from the `Zuora_Account` class `execute()` method.

   ```
   public class MyException extends Exception {}
   ```
2. Add static Boolean crashTest variable in `Zuora_Account` class.
3. In `execute()` method in `Zuora_Account` class add below code

   ```
   if(Test.isRunningTest() && crashTest) {
       throw new MyException('Exception');
   }
   ```
4. Add another test method and set the flag of crashTest = true and call the `execute()` method that will cover the catch block exception

Comment: But i cannot edit main class..Is there any other way by doing changes in Test class only?

Comment: I don't think so there is any other way until & unless you try to set some value from the test class which will then trigger the exception. But i don't find any way of doing this in above code. Salesforce that's way say we require atleast 75% code coverage and not 100% because in some cases you can't cover the code. Only way it to change the main class and throw custom exception.